# Including React Components - Loading time & best practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

Im new to React (coming from AngularJS) & set up a hello world example as follows:

```
<div class="container">

    React says...
    <div class="react-app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        class App extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return <div className="h3">hello react</div>
            }
        }
        var mount = document.querySelector('.react-app');
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, mount);
    </script>

</div>
```

..which prints "hello react" to the page.

In the above example, my React component is placed directly onto the page in a `<script>` tag.

But suppose I wanted to organize my components, placing them in separate js files and including them on the page like so:

```
<div class="container">

    React says...
    <div class="react-app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="path/to/react_component.js" ></script>

</div>
```

This works but there is a noticeable delay between the time "React says..." loads and "hello react".

In AngularJS there is an `ng-cloak` directive to prevent loading of the page while the JS resolves. Is there such a thing for React?

On the other hand, placing the React component directly in the HTML loads everything instantly - should I be placing all my components directly into the HMTL templates? Could get messy with larger components..

Whats the best practice here?

Comment: You should move ALL html into React components. Move `React says...` into your `<App>` component and you won't notice the initial load time. This is best practices. The only element in your `body` should be `<div class="react-app"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/babel">` transpiles JSX during runtime and certanly contributes to initialization time. It can be used for demonstration purposes but isn't supposed to be used in real application. A proper way is to load scripts that were already built.

AngularJS `ng-cloak` doesn't serve the purpose that is suggested in the question.

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

React doesn't have HTML templates that could be displayed in uncompiled form - JSX doesn't appear anywhere but scripts.